# Cheapest way to backup 15TB

Tags: backup

I have 15TB (not GB) of data which I need to backup.  What is the cheapest way to back this up?

At the moment, that data is currently stored on five 3TB HDDs

Comment: The cheapest way?  Carbonite offers a service where you send them your HDDs and they load the data into your cloud service.  There is a cost for that service, and the cost of the hdds, but a tape drive solution would be $1k+ and that would require 15+ tapes at $50+ a pop.

Comment: [Here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16840119058&cm_re=tape-drive-_-40-119-058-_-Product) is an external SCSI 3TB Compress tape drive.  I do believe this question will end up not being on topic.  There isn't a good way to answer this question without suggesting a product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy 4 TB drives, at the time of writing, for $155 Canadian. Four of them would allow you to back up 15 TB of data at a one-time cost of $620. This is cheaper than using AWS Glacier if you plan to keep the data for longer than four months.

It's unlikely you'll be able to find a cheaper option, though it is very likely you'll find more convenient options, or options better suited to your specific use case, which you did not explain.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/) will charge you $0.01 per month per GB, so $150 per month for 15TB. You'll also have to pay some data transfer and retrieval costs to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

It depend's the frequency that you will do and redo this backup. If you will do just one singular backup, to store them as Old archieve Data, maybe can be better buy some Sata HD that is the more cheaper $/GB that you can found.

But if you will need to create one backup job \ routine, is better buy tape drives and install it on one backup server. And after create one full beackup routine (monthly or maybe.. annually) an incremental or differential backup job daily, weekly ou monthly (it will backup only the changed data)